# How can I hide application layout

Tags: android

I have a problem with hiding application layout.

I have tried something like this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
myLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

but it does not work.
I want my main activity to start a service with no User Interface

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What are your expected results, and what is actually happening?

Comment: **"I want my main activity to start a service with no User Interface"** - This is a bad practice. A user should always be given control (and the choice) of how an app works. At the very least there should be a 'start service' button (labelled appropriately) and especially an option to manually 'stop service'.

Comment: I know it is not a standard practice. I'm writing a project for my studies, the subject is to show how easy is to write malware when user accepts permissions. I already have service reading sms inbox, gps tracking and starting on boot, I just have a problem with layout. I want it to be visible only on services list

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the main layout.

To start a Service

1. Create your Service class
2. In your onCreate method , do startService(new Intent(this,YourService.class));

Comment: I have a service already, it is working fine. I just have problem with invisibility

Answer (score 0):

Put your visible content inside of a layout inside the main layout and set that layout to gone instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a simple solution - not to start MainActivity in class running on BOOT_COMPLETED.
Instead of MainActivity start service (START_STICKY)

Answer (score 0):

Please just try to change your app theme to Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar from style.xml which is under the values folder.